# Why is django-nose running tests twice?

Tags: python, django-models, nose, django-testing, django-nose

I have the following **models**:

```
class Poll(models.Model):

    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
             return self.question
```

and the following **test**

```
from polls.models import Poll
from django.test import TestCase
from django.utils import timezone

class PollModelTest(TestCase):

    def test_poll_save(self):
        q = "What is the best OS?"
        pd = timezone.now()
        p = Poll(question=q,
                 pub_date=pd)
        p.save()
        polls = Poll.objects.all()
        self.assertEquals(polls.count(), 1)
        self.assertEquals(polls[0].question, q)
```

and the following **settings**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'polls',
    'django_nose',

)

TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--with-coverage',
    '--cover-package=polls',
    '--with-progressive',
    '--verbosity=0',
    '--with-fixture-bundling',
]
```

When I try `python manage.py test polls` the tests *run twice*. Following is the output:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Name           Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
--------------------------------------------
polls              0      0   100%   
polls.models       6      0   100%   
--------------------------------------------
TOTAL              6      0   100%   

OK!  2 tests, 0 failures, 0 errors in 0.0s
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

However when I try without `TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'`, then the tests runs *only once*. Following is the output:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Please tell me what is wrong? **Why is django-nose running tests twice?**

**OT: django_nose takes more time than unittest, for the same model.**

**EDIT:**

Here is the folder structure:

```
├── database.sqlite
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── 404.html
│   │   ├── 500.html
│   │   └── base.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── polls
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test_models.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably You have Your tests imported twice. You didn't show your file structure, but maybe You have this test in separate file and than you do `import` in tests.py, or something like that.

Comment: @user1629366 So what do You have in `polls/tests/__init__.py` ? do You import test_models there?

Comment: `from test_models import *` thats it.

Comment: So You got Your answer. Remove this line from `polls/tests/__init__.py and` and You will get what You want

Comment: later i will write tests for views, as well and to run all the test, it is recommended, read more alike answers. It is **not** the mistake. How the hell, then django test runs only once!

Comment: @user1629366: django-nose does it for You. It discovers Your tests for You automatically. Putting tests in `__init__.py` is recommended when you are not using django-nose, so decide which recommendatation You follow. 

Uninstall django-nose and put all tests in `__init__.py` or use django-nose and don't care where You put tests and let it find them for You. 

Using django-nose is convenient because You put tests where they fit instead of listing them explicitly in some files.